# starting with umap-learn and I get numba error 'Operands must be the same type, got (i32, i64)'

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I am starting with Python package **umap-learn**. 
The code below terminates with an error in numba package, which seems to be called by umap-learn during complexity reducer creation.

The error is as follows:

`ValueError: Operands must be the same type, got (i32, i64)`

I code in Pycharm 2019.2 (Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.10 amd64) under Windows 10 64-bit.

I used my google-fu and found out the error is most probably caused by the fact that at some level a long variable is handled by Windows at which point it is converted to 32-bit format (I have no idea why that would happen and what that actually means at all) and that's where umap crashes, because it supposedly works in 64-bit environment.

My system is 64-bit and so is supposed to be PyCharm:

```
PyCharm 2019.2 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-192.5728.105, built on July 23, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.10 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 725M
Cores: 4
Registry: 
Non-Bundled Plugins: R4Intellij
```

I never encountered such error when learning Python.
The error showed up when I added the "creator" line.

I am looking for advice on sorting out the problem on Windows 10. I presume this would not happen under Linux, but I prefer to avoid dual-booting my laptop unless there is no other solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here goes the code I run.

*Disclaimer: there are packages not used yet in there, but that should not be causing any trouble.*

````
import numpy
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris, load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot
import seaborn
import pandas
import umap

seaborn.set(style='white', context='notebook', rc={'figure.figsize': (14, 10)})

#load iris dataset
iris = load_iris()

#get iris data into pandas dataframe
iris_df = pandas.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
iris_df['species'] = pandas.Series(iris.target).map(dict(zip(range(3), iris.target_names)))
seaborn.pairplot(iris_df, hue='species')

# create reducer
reducer = umap.UMAP()```






Here is the complete error output:

D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/LMI/Python/sleepwalk/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\errors.py", line 662, in new_error_context
    yield
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 258, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 301, in lower_inst
    val = self.lower_assign(ty, inst)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 459, in lower_assign
    return self.lower_expr(ty, value)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 919, in lower_expr
    res = self.lower_call(resty, expr)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 711, in lower_call
    res = self._lower_call_normal(fnty, expr, signature)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 890, in _lower_call_normal
    res = impl(self.builder, argvals, self.loc)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\targets\base.py", line 1132, in __call__
    res = self._imp(self._context, builder, self._sig, args, loc=loc)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\targets\base.py", line 1157, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\targets\arrayobj.py", line 3374, in numpy_zeros_nd
    ary = _empty_nd_impl(context, builder, arrtype, shapes)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\targets\arrayobj.py", line 3261, in _empty_nd_impl
    arrlen = builder.mul(arrlen, s)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\ir\builder.py", line 24, in wrapped
    % (lhs.type, rhs.type))
ValueError: Operands must be the same type, got (i32, i64)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/LMI/Python/sleepwalk/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import umap
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\umap\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .umap_ import UMAP
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\umap\umap_.py", line 28, in <module>
    import umap.sparse as sparse
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\umap\sparse.py", line 9, in <module>
    from umap.utils import (
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\umap\utils.py", line 108, in <module>
    @numba.njit("f8[:, :, :](i8,i8)")
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\decorators.py", line 186, in wrapper
    disp.compile(sig)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 693, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 76, in compile
    status, retval = self._compile_cached(args, return_type)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 90, in _compile_cached
    retval = self._compile_core(args, return_type)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 108, in _compile_core
    pipeline_class=self.pipeline_class)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 972, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 390, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 903, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 890, in _compile_core
    res = pm.run(self.status)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 266, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 257, in run
    stage()
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 764, in stage_nopython_backend
    self._backend(lowerfn, objectmode=False)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 703, in _backend
    lowered = lowerfn()
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 690, in backend_nopython_mode
    self.metadata)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 1143, in native_lowering_stage
    lower.lower()
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 177, in lower
    self.lower_normal_function(self.fndesc)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 218, in lower_normal_function
    entry_block_tail = self.lower_function_body()
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 243, in lower_function_body
    self.lower_block(block)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py", line 258, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)
  File "C:\Users\Trixx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\errors.py", line 670, in new_error_context
    six.reraise(type(newerr), newerr, tb)
  File "D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\six.py", line 659, in reraise
    raise value
numba.errors.LoweringError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
Operands must be the same type, got (i32, i64)

File "venv\lib\site-packages\umap\utils.py", line 131:
def make_heap(n_points, size):
    <source elided>
    """
    result = np.zeros((3, int(n_points), int(size)), dtype=np.float64)
    ^

[1] During: lowering "$0.14 = call $0.2($0.10, func=$0.2, args=[Var($0.10, D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\umap\utils.py (131))], kws=[('dtype', Var($0.12, D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\umap\utils.py (131)))], vararg=None)" at D:\LMI\Python\sleepwalk\venv\lib\site-packages\umap\utils.py (131)

Process finished with exit code 1
````

Answer (score 2):

Okay,
the problem has been resolved (rather embarrassing, actually].
The cause of my trouble was that the Python interpreter was actually a 32-bit version. Replaced with a 64-bit one and no more errors.